# Snap and APT packages update order

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, snap

Alongside with updating APT packages on startup, I recently added  Snaps auto-refresh (on startup as well) for the snaps that are locally installed as they don't update automatically like the other ones.

But I was wondering if there was a preferred order.

Is it better to update APT packages before/after Snaps, or is it better to update Snaps before/after APT packages?

My personal guess there is no preferred order as Snaps are packaged with their own dependencies, so it shouldn't interfere with APT packages at all.

So I'm looking for confirmation if my gut-feeling is correct.

***Edit:***
The solution I found is to add the following script to the Startup Applications, right after the APT update script.

`gnome-terminal -- bash -c "echo 'sudo snap refresh';pkexec snap refresh;read line;exit 0;$SHELL"`

[image]

***Edit 2:***
The previous ***Edit*** will make the two update processes to run at the same time. A solution I found later is to wrap the tho commands into a single one. This way it will execute `snap refresh` after `update-manager`.

`sh -c "/usr/bin/update-manager && sleep 1 && gnome-terminal -- sh -c \"echo 'sudo snap refresh';pkexec snap refresh;echo '';echo 'Press Enter to close the window...';read line;exit 0;$SHELL\""`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter at all. Snaps and APT packages are independent of each other.

In addition, snap packages update automatically (except for snaps running in devmode, or installed locally), so you shouldn't need to auto-refresh on startup (except in the aforementioned cases).

Comment: Thank you for confirmation.
However, to say that snaps update automatically is not entirely true.
In the case of locally installed snaps, they do not update automatically.
See: https://snapcraft.io/docs/keeping-snaps-up-to-date
I updated my question.

Comment: Thanks, I've clarified my answer.